# How can i make inner recursive function reach original variable in OCaml?

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I am learning OCaml and now stuck with a code.
This is a code that makes a list of the accessible nodes from a graph.

```
type graph = (vertex * vertex) list
and vertex = int

let rec sort lst =
   match lst with
     [] -> []
   | h::t -> insert h (sort t)
 and insert n lst =
   match lst with
     [] -> [n]
   | h::t -> if n <= h then n :: lst else h :: insert n t;;

let rec remove lst =
match lst with
| []       -> []
| x::[]    -> x::[]
| x::y::tl ->
   if x=y then remove (y::tl)
   else x::remove (y::tl);;
     
let rec reach : graph * vertex -> vertex list
= fun (g, v) ->
  match g with
  |[] -> []
  |h::t ->let x = [] in
          match h with
         |a,b -> if a = v then remove(sort(v::x) @ (reach (g, b)))
                  else
                    remove(sort(v::reach (t, v)));;
reach([(1,2);(2,3);(3,4);(4,2);(2,5)],4);;
```

I think my code is meaninglessly complicated due to my lack of coding ability.
Besides, the main problem that I confront now is that I cannot make the recursive function 'reach' to access with original list 'g' as it goes recursive in else condition as it access with list 't'.

## trace says

```
reach <-- ([(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 2); (2, 5)], 4)
reach <-- ([(2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 2); (2, 5)], 4)
reach <-- ([(3, 4); (4, 2); (2, 5)], 4)
reach <-- ([(4, 2); (2, 5)], 4)
reach <-- ([(4, 2); (2, 5)], 2)
reach <-- ([(2, 5)], 2)
reach <-- ([(2, 5)], 5)
reach <-- ([], 5)
reach --> []
reach --> [5]
reach --> [2; 5]
reach --> [2; 5]
reach --> [4; 2; 5]
reach --> [2; 4; 5]
reach --> [2; 4; 5]
reach --> [2; 4; 5]
- : vertex list = [2; 4; 5]
```

First, I claimed a new variable with let y = g and change code

```
|a,b -> if a = v then remove(sort(v::x) @ (reach (y, b)))
                  else
                    remove(sort(v::reach (t, v)));;
```

as I believed that the duplicates will be removed by fun 'remove' and inner function will access with list y, not t which lost its head. However, things did
not go as I planned. It still gives me a same result.
To make function access with original list 'g' in else condition what should I do...?

```
reach <-- ([(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 2); (2, 5)], 4)
reach <-- ([(2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 2); (2, 5)], 4)
reach <-- ([(3, 4); (4, 2); (2, 5)], 4)
reach <-- ([(4, 2); (2, 5)], 4)
reach <-- ([(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 2); (2, 5)], 2)
(*I want function goes back to original list as the variable changes like above*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering directly to your question, here is how to access the original value in a recursive function

```
let to_matrix outer = 
    let rec loop = function
      | [] -> []
      | x :: xs -> [x::outer] @ loop xs in
    loop outer
```

This function will iterate over each element of a list and create a list of list, where each element is a list made of the original element prepended to the whole original list, e.g.,

```
# to_matrix [1;2;3];;
- : int list list =
[[1; 1; 2; 3]; [2; 1; 2; 3]; [3; 1; 2; 3]]
```

The example might be silly, but I hope it clarifies the technique. Here the idea is that we create an inner function, named `loop` in our case, which has its own parameter, and we recurse only on this parameter while leaving the original `outer` list intact.

While it is an idiomatic approach, in general it is not required to create an inner function or an auxiliary function. What is really needed, is an extra parameter, so that at the end of the day we will have two parameters - one which decreases with each iteration and the other which stays invariant, e.g.,

```
let rec to_matrix outer inner = match inner with
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs -> [x::outer] @ to_matrix outer xs
```

the only caveat of this approach is that now we have to pass the list twice, e.g.,

```
to_matrix [1;2;3] [1;2;3];;
```

That's why it is idiomatic to hide this function by a nicer interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an auxiliary function:

```ml
let reach g v = 
  let rec aux g' v' = ... (* here you can use g as the auxiliary function defines g' instead *)
  in aux g v
```

Note that I also define the function with two arguments instead of one tuple, it's more idiomatic :)

Also if `v'` is always the same value the auxiliary function need not redefine it

```ml
let reach g v = 
  let rec aux g' = ... 
  in aux g v
```

One more remark. You can du deeper pattern matching, e.g.:

```ml
  match g with
  |[] -> []
  |(a,b)::t -> let x = [] in
     if a = v
     then remove(sort(v::x) @ (reach (g, b)))
     else remove(sort(v::reach (t, v)));;
```

No need for a second match.

Finally, you might be aware of the `function` keyword that creates a function of one argument creating pattern matching:

```ml
let f x = match x with
(* same as *)
let f = function
```

Therefore:

```ml
let reach (g:graph) (v:vertex) =
  let aux v' = function (*we don't create a g' variable here, we match it straight *)
  | [] -> []
  | (a,b)::t as g' -> (* you can still define the variable in the matching if you need it *)
    let x = [] in
      if a = v
      then remove(sort(v::x) @ (aux b g')) (* or g if that's what you need *)
      else remove(sort(v::aux v t))
  in aux v g
```

would do the same as your code

Edit: correctected recusrive calls to `reach` by recursive calls to `aux` as it wouldn't work.

Comment: PS: as  I read a bit more, I see that your `remove` function is a deduplication function, the name is a bit misleading. The name `x` in `reach` is also quite unclear as to your intention

Comment: As you offered, I tried aux function and define that (a, b):: as g'. I expected that g' would be unchanged in if statement while 'reach' function goes on, but I still got the same consequences and #trace also gives me the same procedure. Doesn't "would do the same as your code" mean that I would do as I intended..?

Comment: `g'` will be different on each call of `aux`. Actually I forgot to call `aux` in the code which is a mistake of mine let me correct. I tried to write code that works exactly like the one you gave as I am not making assumptions on the algorithm you are trying to implement :)

Comment: One thing I notice is the variable x. Did you intend to keep the same list on all the recursive calls ? Mutate it on each recursive calls ?